# Get all null date rows?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get all null date rows from API object. But API `Date2` has value 
`{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}` and SQL table value has null. How will check date? with `null` or `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`?

```
var results = (from CustomerDemographic customerDemographic in customerData.Demographics Where customerDemographic.Date2 == null
                 select new Models.CommunityPreferences()
                  {
                      ....
                      ...
                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: You need to make `Date2` a `nullable` by declaring it as `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` in the class itself, then use `WHERE customerDemographic.Date2.HasValue == false`

Comment: Try comparing against `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: I cannot convert Date2 a nullable. because it is 3rd party API object.

Comment: Then use the `DateTime.MinValue` as indicated in the posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting `{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}`than that means it is [**`DateTime.MinValue`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you are not getting `Nullable<DateTime>` back. You can modify the check like:

```
customerDemographic.Date2 == DateTime.MinValue
```

But a better option would be to modify your mapping class to use `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` for property `Date2`. Currently it is using `DateTime` which is not `Nullable`.